# invalid operation - mismatched types string and nil

Tags: go

I'm trying to create a Go RESTful API that connects to Google Cloud API's.

An issue is happening, described as:
invalid operation: req.ParentId != nil (mismatched types string and nil)

Before creating the local API, I managed to write a Go module that could connect, authenticate, and pull data from Google Cloud. I'm now migrating that module to become a Restful API with paths.

The point of the module was to get a list of all current running Virtual Machines.

Here is the module before changing it to a restful API (which worked):

```golang
package main

import (
    "fmt"

    "example.com/compute"

    "bytes"
)

func main() {
    buf := new(bytes.Buffer)

    // Get a message and print it.
    r.HandleFunc("/virtualmachines", ListAllInstances)
    err := compute.ListAllInstances(buf, "unique-string-id")
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    fmt.Println(buf.String()) // <======= Print buf contents!
}


// new file:

package compute

// [START compute_instances_list_all]
import (
    "context"
    "fmt"
    "io"

    compute "cloud.google.com/go/compute/apiv1"
    "google.golang.org/api/iterator"
    computepb "google.golang.org/genproto/googleapis/cloud/compute/v1"
    "google.golang.org/protobuf/proto"
)

// listAllInstances prints all instances present in a project, grouped by their zone.
func ListAllInstances(w io.Writer, projectID string) error {
    // projectID := "your_project_id"
    ctx := context.Background()
    instancesClient, err := compute.NewInstancesRESTClient(ctx)


    if err != nil {
        return fmt.Errorf("NewInstancesRESTClient: %v", err)
    }
    defer instancesClient.Close()

    // Use the `MaxResults` parameter to limit the number of results that the API returns per response page.
    req := &computepb.AggregatedListInstancesRequest{
        Project:    projectID,
        MaxResults: proto.Uint32(6),
    }

    it := instancesClient.AggregatedList(ctx, req)
    fmt.Fprintf(w, "Instances found:\n")
    // Despite using the `MaxResults` parameter, you don't need to handle the pagination
    // yourself. The returned iterator object handles pagination
    // automatically, returning separated pages as you iterate over the results.

    for {
        pair, err := it.Next()
        if err == iterator.Done {
            break
        }
        if err != nil {
            return err
        }
        instances := pair.Value.Instances
        if len(instances) > 0 {
            fmt.Fprintf(w, "%s\n", pair.Key)
            for _, instance := range instances {
                fmt.Fprintf(w, "- %s %s\n", instance.GetName(), instance.GetMachineType())
            }
        }
    }

    return nil
}
```

The above worked well, even though it might not like pretty.

Below is my effort to move/transition the module to a Restful API:

```golang
package handlers

import (
    "context"
    "fmt"
    "net/http"

    compute "cloud.google.com/go/compute/apiv1"
    "google.golang.org/api/iterator"
    computepb "google.golang.org/genproto/googleapis/cloud/compute/v1"
    "google.golang.org/protobuf/proto"
)

// use Google Cloud compute API to get the list of instance virtual machine instances
func (s *Server) getListAllInstances(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) error {

    ctx := context.Background()
    instancesClient, err := compute.NewInstancesRESTClient(ctx)

    if err != nil {
        return fmt.Errorf("NewInstancesRESTClient: %v", err)
    }
    defer instancesClient.Close()

    // Use the `MaxResults` parameter to limit the number of results that the API returns per response page.
    req := &computepb.AggregatedListInstancesRequest{
        Project:    "unqie-string-id",
        MaxResults: proto.Uint32(16),
    }

    it := instancesClient.AggregatedList(ctx, req)
    fmt.Fprintf(w, "Instances found:\n")
    // Despite using the `MaxResults` parameter, you don't need to handle the pagination
    // yourself. The returned iterator object handles pagination
    // automatically, returning separated pages as you iterate over the results.

    for {
        pair, err := it.Next()
        if err == iterator.Done {
            break
        }
        if err != nil {
            return err
        }
        instances := pair.Value.Instances
        if len(instances) > 0 {
            w.WriteHeader(http.StatusOK)
            fmt.Fprintf(w, "%s\n", pair.Key)
            for _, instance := range instances {
                fmt.Fprintf(w, "- %s %s\n", instance.GetName(), instance.GetMachineType())
            }
        }
    }

    return nil

}
```

**`ParentId` is the culprit (scroll below for the full error). The string I inserted does not seem to work in the code above. Google Cloud API is trying to figure out what parent ID is for the project.
How can I fix the code above?**

*Il leave this code below just for reference*

---

Here is the path that my `api` uses to pull the list of active virtual machines

```golang
package handlers

import "skeleton/api/middlewares"

func (s *Server) InitializeRoutes() {

    s.Router.HandleFunc("/compute", middlewares.MiddlewaresJSON(s.getListAllInstances)).Methods("GET")

}
```

here is my `MiddlewaresJSON`:

```golang
package middlewares

import (
    "log"
    "net/http"
)

// intercept the incoming request, and set one of the headers to Content-Type: application/json
func MiddlewaresJSON(next http.HandlerFunc) http.HandlerFunc {
    return func(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
        // log the route and method
        log.Println("== route: " + r.URL.Path)
        log.Println("== method: " + r.Method)

        // modify the header
        w.Header().Set("Content-Type", "application/json")
        next(w, r)
    }
}
```

Here is the full error:

```
cloud.google.com/go/compute/apiv1
..\go\pkg\mod\cloud.google.com\go@v0.97.0\compute\apiv1\firewall_policies_client.go:684:32: invalid operation: req.ParentId != nil (mismatched typen: req.ParentId != nil (mismatched types string and nil)
```

Here is the code in the library that error is referring too:

```golang
    if req != nil && req.ParentId != nil {
        params.Add("parentId", fmt.Sprintf("%v", req.GetParentId()))
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same issue, solved by downgrading of 1 commit :

```
 go get google.golang.org/genproto@81c1377
```

https://github.com/googleapis/go-genproto/commits/main

Answer (score 0):

Is it error in your code or just in publication?
in publication I see

```
req := &computepb.AggregatedListInstancesRequest{
        Project:    "unqie-string-id,
        MaxResults: proto.Uint32(16),
    }
```

but should be

```
req := &computepb.AggregatedListInstancesRequest{
        Project:    "unqie-string-id",
        MaxResults: proto.Uint32(16),
    }
```

Comment: thats a typo in the publication above! Thanks for catching it though.